# Rails 3: nested form rendered with belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I am struggling to get the nested form rendered with belongs_to association.

I was expecting the address fields in the "_form.html.erb" (below) to be rendered correct, but apparently it is not, and i just cant wrap my head around it to figure why!

Rails version: 3.09

here is the code.

**Model:**

Store.rb

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
  belongs_to :store_address, :foreign_key => "address_id", :class_name => "Address"
  ......

end
```

Address doesn't have any reference to Store model (it is independent)

**Controller**

stores_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @store = Store.new
    @store.build_store_address
    respond_with(@store)
  end
```

**View**

new.html.erb

```
<% form_for(@store, :url => collection_url) do |f| %>
  <%= render :partial => "form", :locals => { :f => f } %>
  <p class="form-buttons">
    <%= button t('continue') %>

  </p>
<% end %>
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%=t(:store_name)%> : <%= text_field :store, :name %>
<%=t(:store_admin_email)%> : <%= text_field :store, :admin_email %>

<fieldset> 
    <legend><label><%=t(:address)%></label></legend> 
    <% f.fields_for :store_address do |address_form| %>
    <table> 
        <tbody><tr> 
            <td width="200"><label><%=t(:line_1)%></label></td><td> 
            <%= address_form.text_area :address1, :rows => 2%> 
            </td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td><label><%=t(:line_2)%></label></td><td> 
            <%= address_form.text_area :address2, :rows => 2 %>  
            </td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td><label><%=t(:city)%></label></td><td> 

            <%= address_form.text_field :city %> 

            </td> 
        </tr> 
.......
```

This renders the store name. but nothing on the address side. please help!

Comment: Did you ever get this working to completion?  You have a similar setup to me, however, when I try and submit the form it doesn't create the store_address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you missed an **=** at **<% f.fields_for ...**. It should be **<%= f.fields_for...** .

This has happened to me so often in the past, missing this one thing, and then wondering why the nested form would not render.

Comment: awww... i knew it had to be something silly.. didn't think it was this silly though ;)

Comment: its plain silly, but very easy to get wrong. i abandoned my program for days when I went through the same situation. :)